# Share queued workload over multiple distinct workers

Tags: python, queue, threadpool

#### About

I am having a class `DataRetriever` which needs to be instantiated with API credentials. I have five different sets of API credentials therefore I want to instantiate five instances of `DataRetriever`. `DataRetriever` only has one public method `retrieve` which will, as the name intends, retrieve some data using [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) based upon an `id` passed to the method.

- a given API credential cannot open more than one stream (with any ID) at the same time
- a `DataRetriever` can only have a maximum of one connection to the API therefore `DataRetriever#retrieve(id)` must not be called on a `DataRetriever` instance that is still retrieving a stream of data
- the amount of data varies so the time until the subprocess exits can be anything in between a few seconds up to multiple minutes

#### Current approach

I am using a [`queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) as seen in the example snippet. I populate the queue with all of the `id`s of the data streams that need to be retrieved.

```py
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        if item is None:
            break
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = queue.Queue()
threads = []
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for item in source():
    q.put(item)

# block until all tasks are done
q.join()

# stop workers
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
    q.put(None)
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

#### Question

I can always go with an observer pattern but I wonder if there is a Python way of doing such a thing?

- How can I make sure `worker` from the code snippet above distributes the queued workload to only idling `DataRetriever`s while using all five instances of `DataRetriever` seamlessly?
- While researching I found out about [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) couldn't adapt the examples to my scenario though. Might this be the solution?

Comment: Only a single DataRetriever can get data from the API at a single time right ?

Comment: @VictorDeleau Thanks for your contribution! No, every single `DataRetriever` can get data from the API simultaneously but an API credential set is bound to one data stream if you will. I will edit my question to make this more clear, sorry about that.

Comment: Ok. And your `worker()` function represents a `DataRetriever` right ? If yes from what I see, a process running the `worker()` function will only read from `q` if the previous task has been processed

Comment: Reading from the queue is blocking by default (i.e. the process will wait for an object to be in the queue to take it), and `multiprocessing.Queue()` are FIFO so you can assume your workers to wait in line for the next job, and jobs must be distributed evenly between workers

Comment: `a API credential set is bound to one data stream, opening another data stream while another one is still in progress will close the first one` do you mean that an API credential is bound to a specific stream ID ? Or just that a given API credential cannot open more than one stream (with any ID) at the same time ?

Comment: The `worker` function is just taken from the example snippet of the python docs. The call of `do_work(item)` is where I need to make sure to call a `DataRetriever` that is free or wait until one is free. I just edited my answer regarding the API credential clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
def worker(q_request, q_response, api_cred):
    dr = DataRetriever(api_cred)
    while True:
        stream_id = q_request.get() # that's blocking unless q.get(False)
        if stream_id == "stop":
            sys.exit(0)
        dr.retrieve(stream_id) # that can take some time (assume blocking)
        q_response.put(stream_id) # signal job has ended to parent process

api_cred = [cred1, cred2, cred3, cred4, cred5]
q_request, q_response = queue.Queue(), queue.Queue()

threads = []
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(q_request, q_response, api_cred[i]))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for item in source():
    q_request.put(item)
    print("Stream ID %s was successfully retrieved." %q_response.get())
```

This assumes that `dr.retrieve(stream_id)` is blocking, or that you have some way of knowing that the subprocess started by `dr.retrieve(stream_id)` haven't finished so your worker would block until it's done (Else the implementation of `DataRetriever` must change).

`q.get()` is blocking by default, so your `worker` processes will wait in line with others for an object to come to take it. `Queue()` object are also FIFO, so you can be sure that the work will be distributed evenly between your `worker` processes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your approach! `DataRetriever#retrieve(id)` is blocking, yes. Is there a reason you are not using q.task_done() like in the example snippet?

Comment: I think that `q.join()` doesn't allow you to know which task was completed exactly, as `q` is shared by several processes. By using another queue you can get this information.

Comment: I did some testing and it seems to work fine using `Queue.task_done()`. The docs state "*For each get() used to fetch a task, a subsequent call to task_done() tells the queue that the processing on the task is complete.*" The description of `queue` states "*It is especially useful in threaded programming when information must be exchanged safely between multiple threads.*". So I am pretty sure `queue` is built in a thread-safe manner that has some kind of mapping between all `Queue.get()` and `Queue.task_done()` calls with corresponding threads.